# While Loop In Tkinter with Pyautogui

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a mouse loop application, I can get the start button to work inside the loop, however the end button seems to crash tkinter instead of close the application.

any advise would be appreciated

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import sys


window = Tk()


def start_loop():
    while True:
        pyautogui.moveTo(3131, 891, 1)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 180
        pyautogui.moveTo(3128, 434, 1)
        

b1 = Button(window, text="Start Mouse", command=start_loop)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)



def end_loop():
    print(sys.exit())
    
b2 = Button(window, text="Stop Mouse", command=end_loop)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be achieved using threading.

It will consume more resources, but I think it would be less "clunky" as a end result.

I added comments about the timing and some print statements to track what is happening:

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import threading
import sys
import time


window = Tk()

t = False

def start_thread():
    """Starts the Mouse thread"""
    global t
    if t:
        return
    t = threading.Thread(target = start_loop)
    setattr(t, "flag", False)
    t.start()
    print("Mouse thread Started")
    
def start_loop():
    """Loop that moves the mouse"""
    t = threading.current_thread()
    time.sleep(0.1) # Just for better printing
    while True:
        print("Mouse thread Running")
        pyautogui.moveTo(3131, 891, 1)
        # Not sure you wanted to adjust the pyautogui time to 180, or just wait 180 seconds.
        #pyautogui.PAUSE = 180
        for x in range(180):
            time.sleep(1)
            flag = getattr(t, "flag")
            if flag:
                print("Mouse thread Stopped")
                return
        pyautogui.moveTo(3128, 434, 1)

def end_loop():
    """Ends the mouse loop"""
    global t
    if not t:
        return
    setattr(t, "flag", True)
    while t.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    t = False
        

b1 = Button(window, text="Start Mouse", command=start_thread)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
b2 = Button(window, text="Stop Mouse", command=end_loop)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, no idea how you figured out how to do this but it's exactly what I wanted and just realised I still have a long way to go to learn phyton.

Comment: @ImraanMhatey The main problem you're going to hit with gui applications are the gui itself needs to constantly be updated, otherwise it will will lag and hang.
Threading and Multiprocessing are the typical ways to run multiple things concurrently or in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, the python course that I'm doing doesn't even mention anything about Threading and Multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `after` function.

In tkinter, it should check each component of interfaces with loop (I mean mainloop).
However, if you use `while True:`, then the GUI cannot check the reactions about the other functions or interfaces like Button.

So, your program can be downed.

```py
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import sys


window = Tk()


def start_loop():
    pyautogui.moveTo(3131, 891, 1)
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 1.8
    pyautogui.moveTo(3128, 434, 1)
    window.after(180, start_loop) //after(ms_for_delay, function)
        

b1 = Button(window, text="Start Mouse", command=start_loop)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)


def end_loop():
    sys.exit()
    
b2 = Button(window, text="Stop Mouse", command=end_loop)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Try this code.

Comment: The gui still will hang, as its pausing mainloop for 180 seconds before executing the second mouse movement.